# 'Segmentation fault' with pthreads and arrary of pointers

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault, pthreads, malloc

Ok, I've hit a wall with my program. I am using pthreads to implement a parallel program, but I have come into a "Segmentation fault" with this block.

```
//This is all in the main function
//{{{{{
//Creates the array that holds pointers to bodies
Body **bodies = new Body*[NUMBER_OF_BODIES];

int bodiesperthread = NUMBER_OF_BODIES / NUMBER_OF_THREADS;

//Creates an array to hold the pthreads
pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];

//Here I partition the array of bodies to each thread
for(int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; j++)
                {
                    if(j == (NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1))
                    {
                        //Create a new array to hold some bodies
                        Body **subbodies = new Body*[bodiesremaining];

                        // Insert the bodies into the new sub array.
                        for(int i = nextindex; i < bodiesremaining; i++)
                            subbodies[i] = bodies[i];

                        // Launch the thread given this sub array.
                        pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, &Tree::updateHelp, (void*)subbodies);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If this is not the last thread we create the sub array with length equal to the
                        // bodies per thread. Then we update bodies remaining.
                        Body **subbodies = new Body*[bodiesperthread];
                        bodiesremaining -= bodiesperthread;

                        // Populate the new array.
                        for(int i = nextindex; i < bodiesperthread; i++)
                            subbodies[i] = bodies[i];

                        nextindex += bodiesperthread + 1;

                        // Launch the thread given the sub array.
                        pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, &Tree::updateHelp, (void*)subbodies);
                    }
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
                    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
       //}}}}




//This is in Tree.cpp

void* Tree::updateHelp(void *bodies)
{
long tid = pthread_self();
Body **subbodies = (Body**)bodies;

//According to the CodeBlocks debugger the fault is occuring here
cout << "Thread " << tid << " has a body at (" << subbodies[0]->x << "," << subbodies[0]->y << ") with mass = " << subbodies[0]->mass << ".\n";
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I am pretty green with c++ and cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting this error. Is it because I have to malloc the threads? Does it have to do with all of the body pointers? Should I create new bodies for the sub arrays?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Try breaking the complicated line where the debugger is telling you the problem happens into several lines, like: 
cout << "Thread ";
cout << tid;
…
Now see if you can figure out exactly what statement is blowing up. Break it down further if you have to, like /*was subbodies[0]->x*/:
Body *first_subbody = subbodies[0];
cout << first_subbody->x;
This will tell you what thing is a bogus pointer, and you can work backwards from there.

Comment: Thank you, Vincent! I split the cout section into several sections; each one uses a different variable to output. The program crashes on

    cout << "has a body at (" << subbodies[0]->x << ",\n";

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Clearly the subbodies array is causing the fault, but I am unsure why.

Comment: `subbodies[0]`does ot seem to carry a valid reference. Did you initialise it? What is `nextindex`? Is it ever set to `0 `?